# Turning column values into Integer columns - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, counter, series, nested-lists

Given a series of unknown size inner list:

```
import pandas as pd
sr = pd.Series([['a', 'b', 'c', 'b'], ['a', 'a', 'd'], ['b']])
```

[out]:

```
0    [a, b, c, b]
1       [a, a, d]
2             [b]
```

The goal is to use values in the inner list to create the columns and populate its value with the count of the items in each row, i.e.

```
     a    b    c    d
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

I have tried achieving the the above by iterating through each row and converting them into `Counter` objects and recreating the dataframe using the list of counter dictionaries:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> pd.DataFrame([dict(Counter(row)) for row in pd.Series([['a', 'b', 'c', 'b'], ['a', 'a', 'd'], ['b']])])
```

**Is there a simpler way to do this?** Perhaps with `.pivot()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if input is `list` like in previous question:

```
lol = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'b'], ['a', 'a', 'd'], ['b']]
df = pd.DataFrame(Counter(x) for x in lol)
print (df)
     a    b    c    d
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

If input is `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sr.values.tolist()).apply(pd.value_counts, 1)
print (df)
     a    b    c    d
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
In [179]: pd.DataFrame(Counter(x) for x in sr)
Out[179]:
     a    b    c    d
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Or

```
In [182]: sr.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(Counter(x)))
Out[182]:
     a    b    c    d
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Or `value_counts`

```
In [170]: sr.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).value_counts())
Out[170]:
     a    b    c    d
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Or

```
In [174]: pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(x).value_counts() for x in sr)
Out[174]:
     a    b    c    d
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
```